# How to select only positive rows from a matrix?

Tags: r, select, matrix

It must be something very obvious but somehow I can't figure it out...

Let's say I have a matrix M like this:

```
       A          B             name.C     name.D         name.E
row 1  0.05160408 0.11090351    1.0206272 -0.318932333    0.2983051
row 2  0.04906006 0.10500725    0.9654350 -0.253736273    0.2883013
row 3  0.04651603 0.09940203    0.9102428 -0.188540213    0.2782974
row 4  0.04397201 0.09413984    0.8550506 -0.123344153    0.2682935
row 5  0.04142799 0.08928137    0.7998585 -0.058148093    0.2582896
row 6  0.03888397 0.08489596    0.7446663  0.007047967    0.2482858
row 7  0.03633994 0.08106041    0.6894741  0.072244028    0.2382819
row 8  0.03379592 0.07785605    0.6342819  0.137440088    0.2282780
```

And I want to subset a matrix with only rows where all the values in names.* columns are positive.

I can produce a logical matrix like that: `M[grep("^name",colnames(M))] > 0`. But how to get the real numbers then? As a matrix, again, not as a vector?

Comment: You can use the abs function for this

Comment: @MarkSmit what `abs()` has to do with anything here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a column index using `grep` for the column names that start with `name`.  Then `subset` those columns and check whether the elements are greater than (`>`) 0.  Then do the sum of each row of the logical index with `rowSums` and check if that equals to the `length` of `indx`.  Use that to subset the rows of `m1`.

```
 indx <- grep('^name', colnames(m1))
 m1[rowSums(m1[,indx]>0)==length(indx),]
 #              A          B    name.C      name.D    name.E
 #row 6 0.03888397 0.08489596 0.7446663 0.007047967 0.2482858
 #row 7 0.03633994 0.08106041 0.6894741 0.072244028 0.2382819
 #row 8 0.03379592 0.07785605 0.6342819 0.137440088 0.2282780
```

Another option would to convert the logical index columns (`m1[,indx]>0`) to `data.frame` and check whether each row have all `TRUE` using `&` and `Reduce`

```
 m1[Reduce(`&`, as.data.frame(m1[,indx] >0)),]
```

Or you could use `apply` with `MARGIN=1` to check the condition for each row.  But, this method may be a bit slower for large datasets. (from @David Arenburg's comments)

```
  m1[apply(m1[, indx], 1, function(x) all(x > 0)), ]
```

#### data

```
 m1 <- structure(c(0.05160408, 0.04906006, 0.04651603, 0.04397201, 0.04142799, 
 0.03888397, 0.03633994, 0.03379592, 0.11090351, 0.10500725, 0.09940203, 
 0.09413984, 0.08928137, 0.08489596, 0.08106041, 0.07785605, 1.0206272, 
 0.965435, 0.9102428, 0.8550506, 0.7998585, 0.7446663, 0.6894741, 
 0.6342819, -0.318932333, -0.253736273, -0.188540213, -0.123344153, 
 -0.058148093, 0.007047967, 0.072244028, 0.137440088, 0.2983051, 
 0.2883013, 0.2782974, 0.2682935, 0.2582896, 0.2482858, 0.2382819, 
 0.228278), .Dim = c(8L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("row 1", "row 2", 
 "row 3", "row 4", "row 5", "row 6", "row 7", "row 8"), c("A", 
 "B", "name.C", "name.D", "name.E")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Personaly I would use `rowSums` for such task , but you can also use another method (for fun) based on `%*%` operator :

```
indx <- grep('^name', colnames(mat)) 
xx = (mat[,indx] >0)%*%t(mat[,indx] >0)
mat[colnames(xx)[diag(xx)==length(indx)],]

#               A          B    name.C      name.D    name.E
# row 6 0.03888397 0.08489596 0.7446663 0.007047967 0.2482858
# row 7 0.03633994 0.08106041 0.6894741 0.072244028 0.2382819
# row 8 0.03379592 0.07785605 0.6342819 0.137440088 0.2282780
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking the data from @Akrun above a oneliner would be:

```
m1[-unique(which(m1[,3:5] < 0) %% nrow(m1)),]
```

explanation:

```
which(m1[,3:5] < 0)
```

gives you the indices of the negative numbers in the columns you are interested in
and with `%% nrow(m1)` you get the row indices where you find negative numbers. You use `unique` as we are only interested in the unique rows.